# Webpack показывает структуру компонентов на продакшн

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Почему webpack показывает структуру проекта на проде ? 
Так всегда было ? Я только сейчас заметил! 
Возможно ли это поправить ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не создавайте source map

Comment: Необходимо отключить генерирование js.map файлов при build'e, либо ограничить к ним доступ

Comment: @AlexeyTen Большое спасибо!

Comment: @StanislavGrot Большое спасибо!